# MegaTools Batch Scripting (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, megasync

I'm using MegaTools to place a file into my Mega directory. I can open up the megacmd window and execute the command directly and it works just fine. When I try to save the command in the batch script, it executes, but I get an error saying that it couldn't log in (API error). It's inserting the exact same thing, so I'm a little confused on why this is. Note: I do have to use double quotes because my password contains special characters.

Works:

```
@rem
@rem Megatools command line with appropriate paths set
@rem
@echo Megatools Shell
@set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%
@cmd
```

After running this, the command window pops up and I am able to run this command just fine:

```
megaput --path "/Root" "c:/Database Backup/Backup.sql" --username myemail@email.com --password "passwithcharacters"
```

But when I try to hard-code the same command into the .bat script:

```
@rem
@rem Megatools command line with appropriate paths set
@rem
@echo Megatools Shell
@set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%
megaput --path "/Root" "c:/Database Backup/Backup.sql" --username myemail@email.com --password "passwithcharacters"
```

It doesn't work. I get an API error saying that I couldn't be logged in.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My password contained a special character that needed to be escaped.

Comment: if it is something so minor, especially human error, do not post an answer, instead delete the question completely.

Comment: imho it may be useful hint for others so it should stay